# Locally Testing Package, Getting ModuleNotFoundError:

Tags: python, pip, package

I followed the [python docs for creating a package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/), but for some reason one of the submodules is not being found. I've looked at other questions that address similar issues, but the solutions have not worked.

Package Structure

```
src/
 board_game_framework/
   __init__.py
   board.py
   cell.py
   game.py
```

Since the only thing that needs to be exposed to the end user is `game.py`, it imports `board.py`, which imports `cell.py`.

I'm able to build and `pip install .` the package, but when I test it with a simple

```py
>>> import board_game_framework
```

I get the following error

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/board_game_framework/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .board import Board
  File "/Users/xxx/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/board_game_framework/board.py", line 3, in <module>
    from cell import Cell, CellValue, Position
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cell'
```

I thought this was an issue with `__init__.py`, but I've tried multiple different ways of importing the modules. I've settled on the following, but could still be wrong.

```
from .cell import Cell, CellValue, Position
from .board import Board
from .game import Game, GameAction, GameDifficulty, GameState
```

I've also tried the following without success.

```
import cell
from board_game_framework import cell
from board_game_framework.cell import cell
from . import cell
```

Comment: "but when I test it with a simple" When you do this, what is the current working directory? What is the `sys.path`? What happens if you try having *only* the relevant import statements in the files? Does it take all four files to demonstrate the error? What needs to be in each file to demonstrate the error? Please read [mre].

Comment: "I've tried... without success: `from board_game_framework.cell import cell`" - well, does `cell.py` actually define something named `cell`? " I've settled on the following, but could still be wrong." Well, what happens when you try them? Which of these is in what file?

Comment: I've tried that pattern for all the components in the `__init__.py` file. Yes `Cel`l is defined in `cell.py` @KarlKnechtel

Comment: Pay attention to capitalization.

Comment: `import cell` will not work because `cell` isn't a top level module.  You should try instead `from board_game_framework import cell`, and please update the question with the error message generated by this import.

Comment: Moveover, you should check `.../board_game_framework/board.py", line 3` as that's where the error line is, given that you had `from .board import Board` (the relative import from `.board`) but you forgot the `.` in front of `cell`.

Comment: Finally, you may have forgotten to reinstall the package after you modified the version that you triggered the install from, thus you never tested the update.  Please try to `pip install .` again, or better, `pip install -e .` to make it editable from your original source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix did not require a change in `__init__.py`. Changing all the imports within the actual code, which needed the full import path. For example

Example: **board.py**

```py
import cell # causing error
import board_game_framework.cell # fix
```

I didn't think this would be the issue since I would have expected it to throw the error when `game.py` import `board.py`, instead of going all the way though to `board.py` importing `cell.py`.

Answer (score 1):

You should rename the `init.py` to `__init__.py`.

And imports need to be like this,

```
from board_game_framework.cell import Cell, CellValue, Position
from board_game_framework.board import Board
from board_game_framework.game import Game, GameAction, GameDifficulty, GameState
```

Comment: I've tried that method, and the naming of `__init__.py` was a typo in the question.